# conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_tableName". The conflict occurred in database "databaseName", table "tableName", column 'id'

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am trying to fill the table " tbl_detail_commande" with data from a form . But when I want to insert the data in database , it gives me this error :

```
conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint FK_tbl_detail_commande_tbl_detail_demande_achat". 
The conflict occurred in database "Gestion Commercial Officielle",  
table"dbo.tbl_detail_demande_achat", column 'id'.The statement has been terminated.'
```

***I tried some solutions :***

1-checking my foreign key relations

2-enable identity_insert  on table "tbl_detail_commande"

But I still get the same error .

***Here is my tables*** : [click her to show tables diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8mjG.png)

***Also here is the code I use to insert data into my database :***

```
String numero_demande = demande.Text;
tbl_detail_commande dc = new tbl_detail_commande();

var id = (from c in db.tbl_detail_commande orderby c.id_detail_commande descending 
select c.id_detail_commande).FirstOrDefault(); 
int valueId = Convert.ToInt32(id.ToString()) + 1;
dc.id_detail_commande = valueId;

var q = (from cc in db.tbl_detail_demande_achat where cc.id_demande == Convert.ToInt32(numero_demande)
select cc.id).Distinct().SingleOrDefault(); 
dc.id_detail_demande = Convert.ToInt32(q);
dc.code_article = Convert.ToInt32(code_article.Text);
dc.id_commande= Convert.ToInt32(num_commande.Text);  
db.tbl_detail_commande.InsertOnSubmit(dc); 
db.SubmitChanges();
```

I dont not what is the problem I just kept turning in circles.Can someone help me please or tell me what I kept doing wrong ?

Comment: The error message means that you are inserting a record to the table `tbl_detail_demande_achat`, but the `id` value does not exist in your other table `tbl_detail_commande`. Check the value of `id` and the existing records in your table `tbl_detail_commande`. You can also check the details of your tables using the SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio).

Comment: @Subbu the value already exists in the table so I dont have thsi probleme . Also I tried to insert data in `tbl_detail_demande_achat` using SSMS and it did work . But When I to insert it using Linq to sql , it dosn't . I verified the code and it works until `db.SubmitChanges()` then it gives me the error .  if it works using sql query ,I really dont get where the error come from .

Comment: I deleted all the diagram tables and I used sql commend to create foreign keys and everything worked like wonders . I dont get why it doesn't work with creating foreign keys in designer :/ ... Anyway thanks A lot for your time and help Sir ! I appreciate it.